# How to pull the server name from a UNC

Tags: c#, regex, uri

Would anyone be able to tell me how to pull the server name out of a UNC?

ex.

//servername/directory/directory

Edit
:
I apologize but it looks like I need to clarify a mistake:  the path actually is more like:

**//servername/d$/directory**

I know this might change things a little

Comment: aren't UNC paths contain backslash characters insted of forward slahes?

Comment: yeah thats really funny.. nobody caught that (including me!)

Comment: @SztupY They are just as valid as forward slashes. I know that is the case now, but not sure if this was also the case in 2009.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about `Uri`:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\servername\d$\directory");
string[] segs = uri.Segments;
string s = "http://" + uri.Host + "/" + 
    string.Join("/", segs, 2, segs.Length - 2) + "/";
```

Answer (score 7):

Just another option, for the sake of showing different options:

```
(?<=^//)[^/]++
```

The server name will be in `\0` or `$0` or simply the result of the function, depending on how you call it and what your language offers.

Explanation in regex comment mode:

```
(?x)      # flag to enable regex comments
(?<=      # begin positive lookbehind
^         # start of line
//        # literal forwardslashes (may need escaping as \/\/ in some languages)
)         # end positive lookbehind
[^/]++    # match any non-/ and keep matching possessively until a / or end of string found.
          # not sure .NET supports the possessive quantifier (++) - a greedy (+) is good enough here.
```

Comment: I tried this one in C# and got the following error message:  parsing "(?<=^//)[^/]++" - Nested quantifier +.

Comment: @Kevin:  just drop the second + symbol.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
^//([^/]+).*
```

The server name is in the first capturing group

Comment: At the start of a line (^), match two forward slashes (//), then one or more (+) characters that's not another forward slash ([^/]) followed by one or more occurrences of anything (.*) The parens "(" and ")" indicate a 'capturing group'.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for explaining how the regular expression actually works.

Comment: @Jason: happy to do so. A mistake in my explanation: the * symbol is not 'one or more', it is 'zero or more'. The + symbol is 'one or more'

Comment: using comment 1 here I get the following in c#:


//servername/


is there a way to strip off the slashes?

(my program)

Regex r = new Regex(@"^//(?<serverName>\w+)/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(@"//servername/directory/directory");

CaptureCollection cc = m.Captures;
foreach (Capture c in cc)
{
 System.Console.WriteLine(c);
}

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression to match `servername`:

```
^//(\w+)
```

Comment: I'm a fan of named capture groups, so I'd probably modify this to: ^//(?<serverName>\w+)/

Comment: \w will match [A-Za-z0-9_] - but server names can contain many more characters than those?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but it just works:

```
var host = uncPath.Split(new [] {'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Uri Host property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.host?view=net-7.0

```
var path = @"\\servername\d$\directory";
var uncPath = new Uri(path);
var serverName = uncPath.Host; // returns "servername"
```