# need a c# regex to get servername out of UNC

Tags: c#, regex, url, uri, unc

I screwed up my last post.  Lets see if I can get this one right..

Would anyone be able to tell me how to pull the server name out of a UNC? (I'm looking for a regex)

this is the string I want to pull the servername from:

```
**\\\servername\d$\directory**
```

My Code is in C#

```
Regex r = new Regex(?????, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match m = r.Match(@"\\servername\d$\directory"); 

CaptureCollection cc = m.Captures;

foreach (Capture c in cc)
{

    System.Console.WriteLine(c);

}
```

I am looking to capture just:  servername

no slashes or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This answer is for education purposes - better to use the Uri object and not re-invent existing functions.**

Same solution as on [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053216/regular-expressions-how-to-pull-the-server-name-from-a-unc), but with backslashes reversed, and therefore escaped, (and possessive quantifier removed, since C# regex doesn't support that):

```
(?<=^\\\\)[^\\]+
```

The server name will be in `\0` or `$0` or simply the result of the function, depending on how you call it and what C# offers.

Explanation in regex comment mode:

```
(?x)      # flag to enable regex comments
(?<=      # begin positive lookbehind
^         # start of line
\\\\      # escaped backslashes to give literal \\ chars.
)         # end positive lookbehind
[^\\]+    # greedily match any non-\ until a \ or end of string found.
```

Answer (score 28):

Why use regex when `Uri` will do it too?

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\servername\d$\directory");
    Console.WriteLine(uri.Host); // servername
    Console.WriteLine(uri.IsUnc); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

This task is simple enough that it does not really require a regex (it would very much be overkill).

Try this approach, which uses a simple call to `string.Split`. It should allow you to get each part of the path trivially (though you say you don't need that).

```
var uncPath = @"\servername\d$\directory";    
var serverName = uncPath.Split('\')[1];
```

If you wanted to do the parsing fully manually, it's still quite straightforward:

```
var serverName = uncPath.Substring(1, uncPath.IndexOf('\', 1) - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  This is likely the best way to do this..

Yeah that's actually what I started with, but in this case I'm just looking for a simple example so I can understand regex better.

Comment: FYI,  C# split is a bugger with that escape character.  

I had to do this:  string server = directory.Split('\\')[2];

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to do it with regex, here is how i would do it.
this produces the results you wanted.

```
string s = @"**\\\servername\d$\directory**";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, @"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*").Captures[0].Value);
Console.ReadLine();
```

produces
servername

you might have to allow for some other potential servername characters like - and _ but this is the basic idea.

But using the Uri class is probably the best way to solve this specific problem.

Comment: actually those asterisks were me trying to get that sentence to bold on this page.  How would it change without them?

Comment: it would be the same without them.

Comment: it is just matching against the potential characters specified in the brackets in the [] brackets.